# How to fetch variable name from calling python script/file into another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, import, inspect

Folder Structure:

```
- main_pkg
  - common_libs
    - utils.py
  - pkg_1
    - main.py
  - pkg_2
    - main.py
```

**utils.py**

```
// Some code here
xyz_var = <GET_IT_FROM_CALLING_FILE>
// Some code here
```

**pkg_1/main.py**

```
xyz_var = 'ABC'
// some code here
```

**pkg_2/main.py**

```
xyz_var = 'XYZ'
// some code here
```

Here, I'm trying to use **utils.py** file by calling from **pkg_1/main.py** or **pkg_2/main.py**. In, utils.py, I would like to use variable called **xyz_var** which varies based on caller script.

I can't simply import it in utils.py; I'm looking for an option where it gets this variable based on calling file.

It will be really appreciated if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: If this value is different for each package, why are you putting it in utils?

Comment: Actually, that's simple logger name otherwise entire file is same no change at all.
For both files, I'm using different logger name. @KelvinDucray

Comment: Could you please provide some more concrete code examples?

Answer (score 0):

utils.py

```
from pkg_1 import main
pkg1_xyz_var = main.xyz_var
#'ABC'
from pkg_2 import main
pkg2_xyz_var = main.xyz_var
#'XYZ'
```

pkg_1/main.py

```
xyz_var = 'ABC'
```

pkg_2/main.py

```
xyz_var = 'XYZ'
```